# Strange behavior by querying DBpedia

Tags: java, jena, dbpedia

I have a java program with jena that has always worked fine.

Since yesterday when the program executes this query

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Moore_%28author%29>
```

on the endpoint "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"

I get this error because (I think) DBpedia returns nothing

```
FINE: Executing query:
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Moore_%28author%29>
GRAVE: ERROR [http-thread-pool-8080-(2)] (RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:44) - Premature end of file.

AVVERTENZA: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFDefaultErrorHandler.fatalError(RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:45)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.fatalError(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:35)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:225)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.fatalError(XMLHandler.java:255)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:142)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:158)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:145)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:215)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:197)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execModel(QueryEngineHTTP.java:161)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execDescribe(QueryEngineHTTP.java:154)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execDescribe(QueryEngineHTTP.java:152)
        at it.unipr.aotlab.dbsoi.sparqlclient.SPARQLClient.executeDescribeQuery(SPARQLClient.java:96)
        at it.unipr.aotlab.dbsoi.logic.DbSoiLogic.getArtistData(DbSoiLogic.java:200)
        at it.unipr.aotlab.dbsoi.logic.DbSoiLogic.execute(DbSoiLogic.java:99)
        at org.apache.jsp.DbSoi_jsp._jspService(DbSoi_jsp.java from :65)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:406)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        ... 52 more
```

I also tried to put the query in the web browser at the address "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"
setting the Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI) with "http://dbpedia.org"

but I get the error

> Errore interpretazione XML: nessun elemento trovato Indirizzo:
>   http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E++++++++%0D%0ADESCRIBE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAlbert_Camus%3E&format=application%2Frdf%2Bxml&timeout=0&debug=on
>   Linea numero 1, colonna 1:

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the query works fine for me in `http://dbpedia.org/sparql` with `http://dbpedia.org` data set name. I get similar error when response time of DBpedia SPARQL endpoint slows down or there is a problem with my connection. But I'm not sure this is the case for you.

Here is a snippet of the result in RDF/XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Moore_%28author%29"><dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink xmlns:dbpedia-owl="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" rdf:resource="http://www.chrismoore.com"/></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Moore_%28author%29"><dbpedia-owl:abstract xmlns:dbpedia-owl="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" xml:lang="es">Christopher Moore es un escritor estadounidense de ficción absurda. Su padre fue policía, y su madre trabajó como vendedora de electrodomésticos en un centro comercial. Creció en Mansfield, Ohio donde empezó a escribir a la edad de 12 años, y estudió en la Ohio State University y en el Brooks Institute of Photography en Santa Barbara, California. Trabajó como vendedor de seguros, camarero, fotógrafo, periodista, obrero en la fabrica de cerámica religiosa (motivos de Navidad)y hasta de DJ. Sus novelas suelen mostrar a personajes normales que se ven envueltos en circunstancias sobrenaturales o extraordinarias. Heredando el humanismo de John Steinbeck y el sentido del absurdo de Kurt Vonnegut, Moore se ha convertido en un admirado autor de best-sellers. Según su entrevista con Writer&#39;s Digest en junio de 2007, los derechos para el cine de su primera novela, La Comedia del Diablo, fueron adquiridos por Disney, incluso antes de que el libro fuera publicado. Sin embargo, la adaptación de las novelas de Moore en películas está lejos de ser cumplida, ya que, durante el tour promocional de ¡Chúpate Esa! (2007), como respuesta a las numerosas preguntas de los fans, Moore respondió que todos sus libros han sido propuestos para hacer películas, o sus derechos comprados, pero que ninguno de ellos &quot;corre de momento el riesgo de ser transformado en película&quot;. En junio de 2006, Moore se trasladó a vivir a San Francisco, California, tras residir unos años en la isla de Kauai, Hawaii.</dbpedia-owl:abstract></rdf:Description>
...
```

Comment: I'm surprised.
The error sometimes occurs and sometimes not!

Probably as you say depends on the load of DBpedia!

thanks
Danilo Brembilla

Comment: Yes, it seems DBPedia is quite unstable in these days, not at all ;)

Comment: @dbrembilla If this answer worked for you (in as much as "DBpedia is flaky sometimes" is a question that has a solution), you should consider accepting it.